# expressjs router not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to MEAN stack, so i am going through tutorials and it pretty clear that not all people use same logic.
But now i am stuck on these two examples

Example One

```
// server.js
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    port = 1337;
// indicating view folder
app.set('views', './views');
// indicating view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
// adding routes
require('./routes/index.js')(app);
require('./routes/user.js')(app);
//
app.listen(port);
module.exports = app;


./routes/index.js
module.exports = function(app) {
    // show indix view
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
            res.render('index', {
                title: 'Index page',
            });
    });
};
```

above we are using `get` method from `app` (which is instance of `express`)

```
./routes/user.js
module.exports = function(app) {
    // showing user page
    app.route('/users').get(function(req, res) {
            res.render('user', {
                title: 'User page'
            });
    });
};
```

above we are using `route` method of `express` and then bind `get` to it

so when the app is running, and i access `localhost:1337` index page is called
and when `localhost:1337/user` is called user page is called

Example two
Now when we use `express myapp` command, this example has some different logic

we have main `app.js`

```
var express = require('express');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

app.listen(1337);

module.exports = app;
```

As you can see first we require `index` and `user` route files required
and then we use `app.use` command to set routes.

in `./routes/index.js` file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

we get method `router` of `express` and then bind `get` method to it

so my question is, when i commit `app.use('/', routes);` and call `localhost:1337` i get error
but we have already using router in `./routes/index.js` to show index page. 
this should work according to first example.

EDIT error msg

```
Error: Not Found
    at app.use.res.render.message (/home/vagrant/meanstack/myapp/app.js:30:15)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/vagrant/meanstack/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/vagrant/meanstack/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
    at /home/vagrant/meanstack/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
    at Function.proto.process_params (/home/vagrant/meanstack/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
    at next (/home/vagrant/meanstack/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
    at SendStream.error (/home/vagrant/meanstack/myapp/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:107:7)
    at SendStream.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at SendStream.error (/home/vagrant/meanstack/myapp/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:244:17)
    at SendStream.onStatError (/home/vagrant/meanstack/myapp/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:340:48)
```

i had this code to handle error

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
})
```

now when i comment this code and comment  `app.use('/', routes);` and run the server.js

i get this when i run `localhost:1337`

```
Cannot GET /
```

if you still cannot see the error, try `express app` in folder and create a new file `server.js` and add below code and run `node server.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

//app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

app.listen(1337);

module.exports = app;
console.log(" call 192.168.33.33:1337");
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: In your example #1, you're using ejs as the view engine, and jade in example #2. Is that on purpose?

Comment: yes, i dont think that matters

Comment: There does not appear to be anything wrong with your code, it worked fine on my machine. What version of express are you using? Look in your package.json file

Comment: try to commit app.use('/', routes); and call localhost:1337 in second example

Comment: did you use express myapp command to generate node app for the second example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69821/discussion-between-iori-and-yzarubin).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I ran express-generator, created a new file server.js with the code you provided. Upon hitting my localhost:1337 I got a 'CANNOT GET /' error. I then uncommented this line inside server.js

```
app.use('/', routes);
```

And it worked.

EDIT:

The reason why you need to call app.use('/', routes) for the route handling to work is because when you call

```
var app = express();
```

At this point, the 'app' variable contains a reference to your express object in memory. Meaning when you call

```
var router = express.Router();
```

Router at this point is standalone object. Router has no reference to the app you created, meaning when you register your GET route with route.get(), it does not affect your app instance of express. Hence when you hit localhost:1337, you get an error until you register the route.

In order to register your router with your app, you need to export and require your router, and register it with

```
routes = require('path/to/router')
app.use('/', routes)
```

The reason why your first example worked, is because in that case, you were registering the route handler directly with your app instance, using app.get()

Comment: Yes that is the point, why did it work, if you see in the first example we are using only app.get not app.use but here we need to use both app.get in ./routes/index.js and app.use in server.js file

Comment: So from what I understood, you're not sure why you need to call BOTH router.get() and then use that as the second argument in app.use(). I've updated my answer, let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: Thank buddy, now i understand why it was not working

Answer (score 0):

`router.get('/todos/active', findByStatusData)`; set the path this way, suppose i faced problem when i use just `router.get('/active', findByStatusData)`; that it shown error,

and also use in `app.use("/todo",todoHandler)`.So now my correct path is `router.get("/todo/todos/active")` and it worked my cased but when i used  `router.get('/active', findByStatusData)` that time i get some unknown error.