# Similar codes working differently . Just a small difference in routes

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

NOT WORKING

home ejs

```
<a href="/animals/new" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add animal</a>
```

animals js

```
router.get("/animals/new",middleware.isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
    res.render("animals/new");
})
```

WORKING
home ejs

```
<a href="/new" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add animal</a>
```

animals js

```
router.get("/new",middleware.isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
    res.render("animals/new");
})
```

middleware isLoggedIn

```
var middlewareobj={};
middlewareobj.isLoggedIn=function(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect("/login");
}
module.exports=middlewareobj;
```

Idk why the first one not working . Help would be appreciated!

Comment: can u elaborate on what the exact issue is? By 'not working' do u mean the route is unreacheable or? and can u share what middleware.isLoggedIn is?

Comment: Yep . its unreachable .

Comment: @arulmanivenkatesh i have added the middleware in code . have a look . With the first route its just not able to even hit the route . Middleware comes later . I tried console.logging something in middleware with first code . But of no use .

Comment: okay let me confirm a few things here... is 'animals' the folder name under 'views'? and is the default view engine set?

Comment: @arulmanivenkatesh . yes . both things are done

Comment: make sure that the router is imported properly and  configured and called properrly into express 'app' variable.

Comment: Thats all i can think of... the above code works good here.... is the code hosted somewhere? so that i can take a better look? I guess the error is with somewhere reg the router import and using it...

Comment: also take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28196421/expressjs-router-not-working

Comment: https://github.com/dhruv-mehta2604/TheAnimalApp